# can't get hello world shell script to run in FreeBSD

Tags: shell-script, executable

Server is running FreeBSD 9.2.

Using vim, I wrote the following script called `hello`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello world"
```

Then I set it as executable:

```
>chmod 755 hello
```

Then I tried to run it from the command line (while in the same folder where the script was saved):

```
>hello
```

I got this error message:

```
hello: Command not found.
```

Is there something different I have to do to make an executable script in BSD?

Comment: This is common to nearly every Unix-like system, and is not specific to (Free)BSD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must type:

```
./hello
```

If you type `hello`, the shell will try to find in `$PATH` any executable program named `hello`. In your case, you have not added your current folder to `$PATH`, so the shell can not find your program.

Dot `.` in `./hello` represent your current working directory, so the shell can expand it to `/full/path/to/hello`.

Comment: Yes, my current folder is not in $PATH.  This works, thank you.